# How can you change a forms layout with code in Acess?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Hello I have a form that makes queries using drop down box's and vb code to change the record source to query different information. However I want to find a way to change the headings after a drop down option is selected.

I.e

If I have a form that displays content from the column headings A B C D but I want to use code to change this to just A and D?

How would I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please do not use unrelated tags. VB.NET has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use datasheet view of form, you can use ColumnHidden property:

```
  Me![A].ColumnHidden =  0
  Me![B].ColumnHidden = -1
  Me![C].ColumnHidden = -1
  Me![D].ColumnHidden =  0
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense but as it's in a seperate form I have to call the opbject and I think I do it like this: subtl_Enter_Hwk_Marks.[hwk1].ColumnHidden = -1 But i just seem to get an error object required?

Comment: if it is separate standalone form use  Forms!subtl_Enter_Hwk_Marks.[hwk1].ColumnHidden = -1

Comment: Ahh got it working with something similar to that. Thanks very much

Comment: if it is child from in main(with dropdown)   Me.subtl_Enter_Hwk_Marks.form![hwk1].ColumnHidden = -1